# Html page interact with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make my html page interact with mongodb. when i'm entering the values in html page the values should store in mongodb but that is not taking place.Help me out.Below is my code.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var url='mongodb://localhost:27017/logindb';


mongoose.connect(url);

app.get('/login.html', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "login.html" );
})
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.end('success');


    var loginSchema=mongoose.Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String});

        console.log("insert");

    var Book=mongoose.model('book',loginSchema,"reg");
    console.log("schema");
    var db=mongoose.connection;
    console.log("conne");
    db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error:'));
    console.log("error");
    db.once('open',function(){
    console.log("connect to DB");

        var book1=new Book({username:res.body.username,
                        password:res.body.password});
    book1.save(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Login saved succesfully");
    });
});
});
app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running!");
});
```

Comment: You can not store data directly from your html to database, you must post your json to an api that store your json. You can use javascript libraries like angularJS to bind your data to html and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to adjust four issues in your code:

1.the `res.end('success');` must be inside your save callback

2.you must use **req.body** to access the request body when posting using Express not **res.body**

3.not use **db.once('open'** because the connection to the database is already open `at mongoose.connect(url);`.

4.your schema must be instantiated once only, for this it must be instantiated globally.

So, your code will be like this :

```
 var express = require('express');

     var app = express();

     var mongoose = require('mongoose');

     var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/logindb';

     var loginSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        password: String
     });

     mongoose.connect(url);

     app.get('/login.html', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "login.html");
     })

     app.post('/', function(req, res) {

        var Book = mongoose.model('book', loginSchema);

        var book1 = new Book({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        book1.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Login saved succesfully");
            res.end('success');
        });
     });

     app.listen(8000, function() {
        console.log("Server is running!");
     });
```